# Convert list elements to numbers

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

There is a csv file with the below three lines.

```
8.84,17.22,13.22,3.84
3.99,11.73,19.66,1.27
16.14,18.72,7.43,11.09
```

I am writing a function which reads lines from a file and appends it to an empty list so that I can use that list for computing mean.

**Below is the code I wrote:**

```
def my_calc(filename):
    mydata = []
    for line in open(filename).readlines():
         mydata = mydata + line.strip().split(',')
    return mydata
```

**Here is the output:**

```
['"8.84', '17.22', '13.22', '3.84"', '"3.99', '11.73', '19.66', '1.27"', '"16.14', '18.72', '7.43', '11.09"']
```

The list elements are strings. How can I convert these to float numbers?

I tried `map()` but I am getting an error message 'could not convert `string` to `float`'.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
a = ['"8.84', '17.22', '13.22', '3.84"', '"3.99', '11.73', '19.66', '1.27"', '"16.14', '18.72', '7.43', '11.09"']
result = map(float, map(lambda x : x.strip('"'), a))
```

Output :

```
[8.84, 17.22, 13.22, 3.84, 3.99, 11.73, 19.66, 1.27, 16.14, 18.72, 7.43, 11.09]
```

In case of python3, do this :

```
result = list(map(float, map(lambda x : x.strip('"'), a)))
```

Comment: I tried your solution, it gives me the message <map object at 0x7f4497fde320> Where I am going wrong?

Comment: @Jarvis- lstrip() and rstrip() helped in getting rid of the double quotes (" "). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your function to append items as float only:

```
import re

def my_calc(filename):
    mydata = []
    for line in open(filename).readlines():
        numbers = map(lambda x: float(x), re.sub("['\"]","",line).split(','))
        mydata.append(numbers)
    return mydata
```

That should give output:

```
[[8.84, 17.22, 13.22, 3.84], [3.99, 11.73, 19.66, 1.27], [16.14, 18.72, 7.43, 11.09]]
```

Comment: It is giving me the same output as earlier.

Comment: I believe you have quotes in your `csv` file which is not listed in the question, please try with the updated code. I have added `strip` to clean the quotes.

Comment: Gone further and added a `re` sub that will remove any quotes period. Make sure you add `import re` before trying.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = ["8.84,17.22,13.22,3.84", "3.99,11.73,19.66,1.27", "3.99,11.73,19.66,1.27"]
result = []
for el in list:
  strings = el.split(',')
  floats = []
  for el_s in strings:
    floats.append(float(el_s))
  result.append(floats)

print(result, type(result[0][0]))
```

https://repl.it/G9oO I'm bad with lambdas, this can help you.

Comment: sorry, this one didn't work as my output had each element wrapped with ' '. The result which you used didn't have that. ['"8.84', '17.22', '13.22', '3.84"', '"3.99', '11.73', '19.66', '1.27"', '"16.14', '18.72', '7.43', '11.09"']

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for posting your answers!

Here's my solution. I took bits and pieces of all your solutions to come up with this one.

```
# Workable solution
mylist = []
a = ['"8.84', '17.22', '13.22', '3.84"', '"3.99', '11.73', '19.66', '1.27"', '"16.14', '18.72', '7.43', '11.09"']
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    mylist.append(a[i].lstrip('"').rstrip('"'))
    mylist = [float(x) for x in mylist]
print(mylist)
```

**Output:**

```
[8.84, 17.22, 13.22, 3.84, 3.99, 11.73, 19.66, 1.27, 16.14, 18.72, 7.43, 11.09]
```